# Los métodos en plugin de Mongoose no se ejecutan

Tags: javascript, mongoose

No logro darme cuenta porque `schema.method.log` y `pre.('save'...)` no funciona.

Desde antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda!

```js
// plugin.js
const LogSchema = require('../models/log');

const plugin = function (schema) {

  schema.post('init', doc => {
    console.log(doc);
  });

  schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    console.log('save') // <---------- NO SE EJECUTA
    next();
  });

  schema.methods.log = function(data) {
    return LogSchema.create(data);
  }
}

module.exports = plugin;
```

A continuación dejo la ruta donde se procesa el método POST, para agregar un producto:

```js
// products.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Products = mongoose.model('products');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => { // <--- POST method
  const product = new Products({
    name: req.body.name,
  });

  console.log(typeof product.log); // <---------- UNDEFINED !

  await product.save(); // <--- EL PRODUCTO SE GUARDA CORRECTAMENTE

  res.json({
    status: 'Product Saved'
  });
});
```

```js
// index.js

[...]

mongoose.plugin(require('./server/middlewares/plugin.js'));

[...]
```

Soy relativamente nuevo en Mongoose, no tengo una comprensión tan profunda como para resolver el problema, hace días que estoy dando vueltas con este tema.

Comment: Existe la posibilidad que estés creando tu Modelo antes de la llamada a tu Plugin, en dicho caso ningún método del Plugin estará disponible en el modelo. Tu código luce válido. Verifica el orden en que realizas la importación de módulos en tu archivo `index.js`.

Comment: Efectivamente ese fue el problema, el orden de las importaciones en index.js. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Escribiré una respuesta, ya que es un problema algo común. Así quien se enfrente a una situación parecida encontrará una respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

`Mongoose` no es parte de `MongoDB`. En realidad es como un plugin o modulo añadido en `node.js`, entonces la pregunta es ¿Ya instalaste `mongoose`?

Se instala de esta manera:

```
npm install mongoose --save
npm install mongoose-pagination --save
```

Comment: Hola, sisi lo instale perfecto y vengo usandolo sin complicaciones. El problema aparece cuando quiero agregarle  plugins para ejecutar metodos en todos los esquemas. Gracias